# How to use href attribute of the anchor tag in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

How to access the href attribute and assign the value of href attribute to a variable in jQuery in following scenario? Can you help me in this regard?

```
<a class="c-icn c-edit-n" href="{$control_url}modules/tests/manage_tests.php?op=delete&test_id={$all_tests[tests].test_id}&test_mode={$test_mode}&test_type={$test_type}{$query_string}" onClick="return ConfirmDelete('{$all_tests[tests].test_name} | {$all_tests[tests].test_code}', '{$all_tests[tests].is_test_user_assigned}', '{$all_tests[tests].is_test_question_assigned}')" title="Delete test">delete</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
// Selecting
$("a.c-icn").prop('href');
// assigning
$("a.c-icn").prop('href', "your value");
```

Difference between prop and attr:

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var yourLink = "whatever.com"; // or any address

//set like that
$('a.c-icn').attr("href", yourLink);

//get like this
var getLink = $('a.c-icn').attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the thing and then apply changes:

```
var thing = $(".c-icn");
var currentHref = thing.attr("href");
var newHref = currentHref
  .replace("{$placeholder1}", "someValue1")
  .replace("{$placeholder2}", "someValue2");
thing.attr("href", newHref);
```

Obviously being more specific to your requirements to search & replace; not to mention finding the correct link, which you don't specify as a requirement but I'm sure exists.